# Automatically open a screen in flutter app on getting a background push notification

Tags: flutter

I want to know if the following is possible in flutter using flutter firebase messaging (FCM)

Scenario:
The app is closed or killed. A firebase push message is sent to the device (or device is listening on some topic etc.). The app gets the notification in the background and based on a flag in the data, either shows a notification in the notification tray or opens the app and displays a modal dialog to alert the user of an emergency notification. This has to happen automatically without having the user to click on the notification

Use case,
Any notification with medium severity that comes in can be displayed as a notification in the notification tray. The user can click on it and open the app whenever he wants to

Any notification with critical severity and which requires immediate user attention needs to automatically show a modal dialog with some buttons to enable the user to take action. It must play some sound to get the users attention.

I have done this in android previously where we used to get the notification in the notification handler and then based on the incoming message data, we used to either show a notification or show a dialog.

Comment: did you find some help?

Comment: @Abbas did you find someting?

Comment: I had to switch to a different project so currently not after it. But yes, with native code it's possible to run a background service. This is the only solution I know of so far.